# How to copy all images from disk to single directory using mc

Tags: file-copy, mc

I have very messy disk with many images in many folders. How I could copy only all files with .jpg extension to another disk into single directory? Probably there are many images with same name but I want to keep them all, just add annother number to end for example.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `mc`, I'd suggest a bit of `bash` work in conjunction with the `find` command:

```
id=0; 
s=.jpg; 
while read f; do 
    cp $f targetdir/$(basename $f $s)$((id+=1))$s
done < <(find sourcedir -name '*'$s)
```

or, as a one-liner:

```
id=0;s=.jpg;while read f; do cp $f targetdir/$(basename $f $s)$((id+=1))$s; done < <(find sourcedir -name '*'$s)
```

Replace `sourcedir` by the root of the source directory tree, and `targetdir` by the desired target directory to copy the files into. The `find` command will recursively descend into the source tree.

This will preserve files with identical filenames from different directories because a counter is added to each target file name to make it unique.